# The footer div is not showing when an error comes up on upload

Tags: php, html

The footer is included in the index file with the include code leading to this page like this

```
 <?php include "footer.php" ?>

 <center><div id="content"><br>
 <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" class="file" name="userfile"/><br>
 <br>
 <button name="upload" type="submit" value="Submit" class="upload">Upload</button>
 </form>
 <?php
 if(isset($_POST['upload'])) {

 $allowed_filetypes = array('.jpg','.jpeg','.png','.gif');
 $max_filesize = 10485760;
 $upload_path = 'useruploads/';
 $description = $_POST['imgdesc'];

 $filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
 $ext = substr($filename, strpos($filename,'.'), strlen($filename)-1);

 if(!in_array($ext,$allowed_filetypes))
 die('<h4>The file you attempted to upload is not allowed.');

 if(filesize($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']) > $max_filesize)
 die('<h4>The file you attempted to upload is too large.');

 if(!is_writable($upload_path))
 die('<h4>You cannot upload to the specified directory, please CHMOD it to 777.');

 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],$upload_path . $filename)) {
 $query = "INSERT INTO uploads (name, description) VALUES ($filename, $description)"; 
 mysql_query($query);

 echo '<h5>Your file upload was successful!';


 } else {
 echo '<h4>There was an error during the file upload.  Please try again.';
 }
 }
 ?>
 </div>
```

If you want to see for you're self i have temporary uploaded this script to my site so you can see the error for you're self try and upload something that is not a image file and you will see the error, and i was seeing if it was possilbe to add a button after the upload is complete to link it to the image

[Website Link](http://owainstevens.com)

Here is also the footer code

```
<center><div id="footer">
<p>Copyright &copy; OSPICTUREVAU 2014</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `die` to output your errors which will stop execution of all code after the `die` statement. This means that your footer code is never executed.

Redirecton error:

```
if (!in_array($ext, $allowed_filetypes))
    {
    header("Location: errorpage.php");
    exit;
    }
```

You could pass error codes to the `errorpage.php` to give the user a meaningful error message.

Comment: if i don't use the die then anyone can upload the file even tho it will still say error

Comment: You could redirect away from the upload script to an error page. The die statement kills all further execution of the script.

Comment: don't know how to do that haha

Comment: That wasn't the question.

Comment: ill look for some redirects online